# Can't send a message from server to client with socket.io

Tags: socket.io

I'm new to socket.io and was trying to send a message from server to client while following the instructions of basic emit on https://socket.io/docs/v4/emitting-events/. I expected when I connected to the socket, I would have the word 'world' printed on the console but I failed without knowing why. Did I do something wrong?

Server

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  io.emit('welcome', 'world');
});

http.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Socket.IO server running at http://localhost:${port}/`);
});
```

Client

```
var socket = io();

socket.on('welcome', (arg) => {
  console.log(arg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After io.on('connection') You have to receive message from client using

```
socket.on('welcome',(data) {
     //from there emit to client receive message
}) ;
```

Comment: And from client side the same socket.on function to receive the message to the client